# php regex to replace 'any' slashes in a path with directory separator

Tags: php

I am trying to take paths like this:

some/path/here
some\other\path

and replace each slash in the paths with PHP's DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR built in constant

I have this:

```
$subject = '/asdf';
$var = preg_replace('#\\\\#', DS, $subject);
print $var;
```

but this doesn't replace, it only add.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than using `preg_replace`, why not just use `str_replace`?

```
$var = str_replace(array('/', '\\'), DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $subject);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

Because you have 2 slashes try with `#\\#`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't explicitly need regex, then this is the way:

```
$string = "some/path/here some\other\path";
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$result = str_replace(array("/","\\"),$ds,$string);
echo $result;
```

Outputs: **some/path/here some/other/path**

Answer (score 0):

It should replace, not add. But try this:

```
preg_replace('/[\\]/', DS, $subject);
```

Should also work.